# start clang static analyzer with xcodebuild

Tags: xcodebuild, clang-static-analyzer

I'm trying to set up clang static analyzer on a hudson build server and if I follow the advises [in this blog post](http://osx-ci.blogspot.com/2009/08/hudson-iphone-xcode-and-unit-testing.html) I've got the following errors:

```
cc1obj: error: unrecognized command line option "-fdiagnostics-print-source-range-info"
cc1obj: warnings being treated as errors
cc1obj: warning: -Wuninitialized is not supported without -O
Command /usr/local/bin/libexec/ccc-analyzer failed with exit code 1
Command /usr/local/bin/libexec/ccc-analyzer failed with exit code 1
```

and if I pass `RUN_CLANG_STATIC_ANALYZER` parameter to the `xcodebuild` (without using `scan-build`) it generates me a few plist files but I have no idea how to present those files to user because I expect for HTML output.

Does anybody succeed with this?

Answer (score 1):

With Xcode 4 you can create .xcconfig files to override any methods in the project build settings.  In this case make a myConfig.xcconfig and put RUN_CLANG_STATIC_ANALYZER = YES;  then you can run it by calling "xcodebuild -xcconfig myConfig.xcconfig"

Answer (score 0):

It's been more than two years since I asked this question and I decided to use [OCLint](http://oclint.org/) for this purpose. Looks like a more configurable option and it supports xcodebuild from the box.